# how we can change the format of specific cell to our desired format before taking cell content phpexcel?

Tags: phpexcel

I should read data from more than 4 different excel file with different cell formating but same data within, so how i can change the cell format then read the data using phpexcel?

Comment: for example cell A1 has number 435546567567345 as content but in one of the files this cell format is set as general and it seems as 5.4354343+E14 but when i double click on cell it show the real number so how i should take this value?

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing a numeric value that's longer than a 32-bit signed integer can handle (such as 435546567567345) then treat it as a string using

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValueExplicit(
        'A1', 
        '435546567567345', 
        PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING
    )
```

**EDIT**

If you're reading this value from an Excel worksheet, and it is actually a number value rather than a string containing a numeric value, then it is likely being treated as a float by MS Excel, so there may well be some loss of precision already (unless the file was created using a 64-bit version of MS Excel), even before PHPExcel reads it. If it is a number created using a 64-bit version of MS Excel, then you'll need a 64-bit version of PHP to read it without loss of precision.

Try reading the raw, unformatted value using `getValue()` and then doing a var_dump() to see what datatype it actually is; or try using `getDataType()` to see what the value was being stored as in the Excel file

Comment: Problem is in reading of cell value i can not take the hole digit of number from that cell 2 or 3 digit always remain when i take the value.